# How to get sexagesimal on google maps, and cacluate distance between two sexagecimal?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to calculate distance between two point using latitude and longitude. But now i have project,it must calculate distance between two point using sexagesimal like this link [Calculate](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)., and get  sexagesimal with google maps, i get this [Link](http://astroxa.blogspot.com/2009/04/latitude-longitude-from-google-maps.html) but i don't know how to do that. Anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: _sexagesimal_? Maybe you mean _minute_?

Comment: [Sexagesimal](http://astroxa.blogspot.com/2009/04/latitude-longitude-from-google-maps.html). i want to get sexagecimal from a point on google maps like that link, the first. And then i want distance not minute calculate this sexagecimal like this link [Calculate](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points in google map is usually in decimal format. You can take the points in decimal and convert it to sexagesimal using the follow method as given in the link http://www.sunearthtools.com/dp/tools/conversion.php#txtCnv_2 :

```
# You have decimal degrees (-73.9874°) instead of degrees, minutes, and seconds (-73° 59’ 14.64")
# The whole units of degrees will remain the same (-73.9874° longitude, start with 73°)
# Multiply the decimal by 60 (0.9874 * 60 = 59.244)
# The whole number becomes the minutes (59’)
# Take the remaining decimal and multiply by 60. (0.244 * 60 = 14.64)
# The resulting number becomes the seconds (14.64"). Seconds can remain as a decimal.
# Take your three sets of numbers and put them together, using the symbols for degrees (°), minutes (’), and seconds (") (-73° 59’ 14.64" longitude)
```

I am assuming you know how to get the points from google maps. You already know how to calculate the distance using latitude and longitude. Calculating the distance in decimal or in sexagesimal will give you the same answer. You will just need to convert it from one form to the other. Let me know if you have any other clarifications.

Comment: Yes actually same but my project need sexagesimal to get distance.

Comment: If the points are already in sexagesimal then you can convert them to decimal format. The link I have posted above has the conversion from sexagesimal format to decimal format too. I am not really sure what your exact requirements are. If you could elaborate it in a more detailed manner I am sure others will be able to help.

Comment: My project need sexagecimal, couse  using Floyd Warshall Algorithm. I have manual calculate for my project. Before u give me solution, i confuse how to convert latitude and longitude into sexagesimal. But now i'm understand.